# How to copy files from one document set to another document set

Tags: development, document-set

In a event receiver depending on some business rules, I need to copy the Document Set CONTENTS to another existing document set.  However I cant find how to do it.  I have the code that gets the source document set and the target document set.  However I dont know how to copy the files.

And I can not use the DocumentSet.CopyTo, because the document set already exists, and it will overwrite the metadata on the existing document set.

```
private void CopyAgendaPointAttachmentsToRootSite(SPListItem agendaPointItem)
        {
            try
            {
                if (agendaPointItem != null)
                {
                    SPWeb currentSite = agendaPointItem.ParentList.ParentWeb;
                    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                    {
                        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(currentSite.Site.RootWeb.Url))
                        {
                            using (SPWeb elevatedTargetWeb = site.OpenWeb())
                            {
                                SPList targetList = GetAgendaPointProposedTargetLibrary(agendaPointItem, elevatedTargetWeb);
                                DocumentSet targetDocumentSet = DocumentSet.GetDocumentSet(targetList.RootFolder);

                                SPDocumentLibrary targetDocumentLibrary = (SPDocumentLibrary)targetList;
                                SPContentTypeId targetCTId = targetList.ContentTypes.BestMatch(new SPContentTypeId(MeetingsCommon.Constants.CONTENTTYPES_AGENDAPOINTPROPOSED_ID));
                                DocumentSet documentSet = DocumentSet.GetDocumentSet(agendaPointItem.Folder);
                                if (documentSet != null)
                                {
                                    foreach (SPFile file in documentSet.Folder.Files)
                                    {
                                                      string copyToUrl = string.Concat(elevatedTargetWeb.Url, "/", targetList.RootFolder.Url, "/", agendaPointItem.Name, "/", file.Name);


                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogError("AgendaPointsEvents", "CopyAgendaPointAttachmentsToRootSite(SPListItem agendapointItem)", ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

**Update:1**
*The exception thrown is Value does not fall within the expected range in the Copy Line, I checked with the debugger the url and its fine, because I can just copy and paste it in the browser and it works*

**Update 2:**

```
Both DocumentSets are in different SPWeb objects
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, a few assumptions here, based on the code you posted:

1. The target document set exists in a library in the root web of the site collection
2. The origin document set exists in the same site collection, but in a sub-web somewhere
3. The target document set already exists and is named exactly the same as the origin document set
4. The `SPListItem agendaPointItem` passed into the method is the list item representing the origin document set

If these assumptions are correct, could you not just do:

```
SPWeb currentSite = agendaPointItem.ParentList.ParentWeb;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    // you can stack your usings, you don't have to nest them
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(currentSite.Site.RootWeb.Url))
    using (SPWeb elevatedTargetWeb = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList targetList = GetAgendaPointProposedTargetLibrary(agendaPointItem, elevatedTargetWeb);

        // this line assumes that the target document set is in the root of the target library
        // and not inside some subfolder in the target library
        SPFolder targetFolder = targetList.RootFolder.Subfolders[agendaPointItem.Folder.Name];

        foreach (SPFile file in agendaPointItem.Folder.Files)
        {
            string copyToUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", targetFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, file.Name);
            file.CopyTo(copyToUrl, true);
        }

        elevatedTargetWeb.Update();
    }
});
```

This way you don't need to fool around with the DocumentSet objects at all, just move the files from one folder to another.

Comment: I tried your code but I get this: Value does not fall within the expected range. in the copyto call. The value of the copyToUrl variable is: /AgendaPointsProposedCor/379db39b-15ed-4f5f-a244-3ab3d87f1533/sample-loterij.txt   I wonder if it should have maybe the http://myservername/  and then the rest?

Comment: I had to use SPweb.files.add with a full url and then it works

Comment: I'm wondering if it also might work (using the server relative url) by doing `targetFolder.Files.Add`.  Glad you got it working in the end, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static SPFile CopyFile(SPWeb web, string sourceUrl, DocumentSet docSet)
{
 SPFile file = web.GetFile(sourceUrl);
 string destinationFolderUrl = docSet.Folder.Url;

 destinationFolderUrl = (!destinationFolderUrl.EndsWith("/")) ? destinationFolderUrl + "/" : destinationFolderUrl;
 file.CopyTo(destinationFolderUrl + file.Name, true);
 web.Update();

 return web.GetFile(web.Url + "/" + destinationFolderUrl + file.Name);
}
```

http://howtosharepoint.blogspot.in/2010/12/programmatically-create-document-set.html

check this link

Comment: I think I am mmissing the file name at the end, testing....

Comment: pls see my update1